# Retry request in scrapy downloader middleware

Tags: python, web-scraping, proxy, scrapy, scrapoxy

I use scrapoxy which implements IP rotation while **scraping**.

I have a list `BLACKLIST_HTTP_STATUS_CODES` of status codes that indicate that the current IP is blocked.

**The problem**: once you got a response with status code in `BLACKLIST_HTTP_STATUS_CODES` scrapoxy downloader middleware raises IgnoreRequest and then changes IP. As the result my script skips the url whose response got bad status code.

Example of logs:

```
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.some-website.com/profile/190> (referer: None)
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.some-website.com/profile/191> (referer: None)
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.some-website.com/profile/192> (referer: None)
[spider] DEBUG: Ignoring Blacklisted response https://www.some-website.com/profile/193: HTTP status 429
[urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): 13.33.33.37:8889
[urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: http://13.33.33.37:8889 "POST /api/instances/stop HTTP/1.1" 200 11
[spider] DEBUG: Remove: instance removed (1 instances remaining)
[spider] INFO: Sleeping 89 seconds
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.some-website.com/profile/194> (referer: None)
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.some-website.com/profile/195> (referer: None)
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.some-website.com/profile/196> (referer: None)
```

As the result my script skipped `https://www.some-website.com/profile/193`.

**The goal**: I want to retry request whose response got status code that is in `BLACKLIST_HTTP_STATUS_CODES` until it is not in that list.

**My DownloaderMiddleware looks like that**:

```
class BlacklistDownloaderMiddleware(object):
     def __init__(self, crawler):
         ...
    
     def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
         ...
    
     def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        """
        Detect blacklisted response and stop the instance if necessary.
        """
        try:
            # self._http_status_codes is actually BLACKLIST_HTTP_STATUS_CODES
            if response.status in self._http_status_codes:
                # I have defined BlacklistErorr
                raise BlacklistError(response, 'HTTP status {}'.format(response.status))
            return response

        # THIS IS HOW ORIGINAL CODE LOOKS
        except BlacklistError as ex:
            # Some logs
            spider.log('Ignoring Blacklisted response {0}: {1}'.format(response.url, ex.message), level=logging.DEBUG)
            # Get the name of proxy that I need to change
            name = response.headers['x-cache-proxyname'].decode('utf-8')
            # Change the proxy
            self._stop_and_sleep(spider, name)
            # drop the url
            raise IgnoreRequest()

            # MY TRY: I have tried this instead of raising IgnoreRequest but
            # it does not work and asks for arguments spider and
            # response for self.process_response
            # return Request(response.url, callback=self.process_response, dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: why are you getting blacklisted? is there a rate limit you aren't following?

Comment: @SuperStew I guess I hit some requests limits. How does it relate to the question, though

Comment: You can use IP rotation and captcha resolver as a layer to your scraper to avoid getting blocked and/or reaching the request rate limit. I saw this article helped me handle this kind of issue. Cheers!
https://medium.com/@scraperguy/this-could-be-the-answer-to-your-web-scraping-problems-66c88e775c42

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning a new Request object, you should copy the original request like `retry = request.copy()`. You could check out how [Scrapy's `RetryMiddleware` handles retries](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/retry.py).

For your reference:

```py
def _retry(self, request):
    ...
    retryreq = request.copy()
    retryreq.dont_filter = True
    ...
    return retryreq
```

And you could call it like

```py
def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    try:
        if response.status in self._http_status_codes:
            name = response.headers['x-cache-proxyname'].decode('utf-8')
            self._stop_and_sleep(spider, name)
            return self._retry(request)
        return response
```

This should give you the idea.